# Best way to test logging?

Tags: .net, logging, moq, xunit

My code logs with an ILogger like this:

```
public class Calculator
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Calculator(ILogger<Calculator> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;

        _logger.LogInformation("The sum of {x} and {y} is {sum}.", x, y, sum);

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now I want to be sure, that when I call Sum(2,3) the LogInformation contains the numbers 2, 3 and 5.
How to catch that in Xunit (Moq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me, I'd use [Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging](https://github.com/rgvlee/Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging) (disclaimer: I am the author) to build the expression. It's designed for this exact purpose and provides a simple, readable statement.

```
loggerMock.Verify(Log.With.LogLevel(LogLevel.Information).And.LogMessage("The sum of {x} and {y} is {sum}.").And.LoggedValue("x", 2).And.LoggedValue("y", 3).And.LoggedValue("sum", 5), Times.Once);
```

If you want to roll your own you will need to perform your verify on the `Log` method and match on the log level and the read only list that contains the message/logged values.

The log level is straightforward. To match on the message/logged values you need to add a matcher on the `TState` parameter (the 3rd parameter) as per below:

```
var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<Calculator>>();
var logger = loggerMock.Object;
var calculator = new Calculator(logger);

calculator.Sum(2, 3);

loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(
    It.Is<LogLevel>(x => x.Equals(LogLevel.Information)),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) =>
        ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)o).Last().Value.ToString().Equals("The sum of {x} and {y} is {sum}.") &&
        ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)o).Any(y => y.Key.Equals("x") && y.Value.Equals(2)) &&
        ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)o).Any(y => y.Key.Equals("y") && y.Value.Equals(3)) &&
        ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)o).Any(y => y.Key.Equals("sum") && y.Value.Equals(5))
    ),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),
Times.Once);
```

Under the covers TState is a `FormattedLogValues` object which implements `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. `FormattedLogValues` is internal in .NET Core 3.* so you can't access it. The last item is `{OriginalFormat}` which is the log message as provided to the logger.